# Invalid number of rows in section Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, reloaddata

I have a dictionnary of array who contain class Card(), I have a button who call a function who move one array

```
    static var DeliveryStatusArray =
    [
        "claimable": [Card](),
        "onTime": [Card](),
        "future": [Card](),
        "claimDone": [Card](),
        "tooOld": [Card](),
    ]
```

My fonction for move my Card is

```
    static func moveCard(card:Card) -> Void {
    var pos:Int = -1
    var index:Int = 0
    while(index < (DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?.count)!)
    {
        if (DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?[index].idCard == card.idCard)
        {
            pos = index
        }
        index += 1
    }
    if (pos > -1)
    {
        let card:Card = (DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?[pos])!
        DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?.remove(at: pos)
        DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimDone"]?.append(card)
    }
}
```

When It's done I post a notification to my view for calling this function

```
    func notificationFinish(notification:Notification) -> Void{
        let sectionClaimable:Int = (api.dictionary["delivery"]?.index(of: "claimable"))! // Is 1
        let sectionClaiDone: Int = (api.dictionary["delivery"]?.index(of: "claimDone"))! // Is 4
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionClaimable), with: .top)
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionClaimDone), with: .top)
        return
    }
```

First loop I got 2 cards in * DeliveryStatusArray["claimDone]* and after calling *moveCard()* I have three card

I got the error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 4.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I can't get more items when I reload my data ?

Comment: Top tip… start your property names with lower case letters, e.g. `deliveryStatusArray` to distinguish from classes

Comment: Thanks for you tip !

Comment: Can you explain what `moveCard` is _supposed_ to do?

Comment: Move a card from an array to another, 
Exemple Function copy  a card from DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray["claimable"] put in in tmp var, remove the card from "claimable" and .append the card in "claimDone"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be…

```
// Get the index of card in claimable with matching idCard
guard let index = deliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?.index(where: {$0.idCard == card.idCard }) else { return }

// Remove the card at that index
let card = deliveryStatusArray["claimable"]?.remove(at: index)

// Append the card
deliveryStatusArray["claimDone"]?.append(card)
```